# Are the USB-C D+ and D- shorted to its duplicate pair pin?

Tags: cables

- Is the usb type C connector Data + and Data - are shorted to its pair on the opposite side?
- Are the Vbuses shorted to the other V buses?
- And does the question above still hold true/false if the cable is type-C to type-A or if the cable is type-C to type-C?

[image]

Comment: you misunderstood my question sir, what i mean is, is A6(D+) shorted to is opposite pair B6(D+), and A7(D-) and B7(D-). striping a usb C cable is a little bit to expensive for me to do.

Comment: the connector has 24 pins ... any interconnects between pins would be done by the use of a small PCB or by wire jumpers at the connector ... i would guess that the cable manufacturer would use the least number of wires in the cable

Comment: @jsotola so are they shorted?

Answer (score 2):

D+ and D- duplicates are not shorted, because there is only one differential pair in the cable.
At least in the cables I tested - using 24-pin receptacle breakout boards.

D+ and D- duplicate pins from the Type-C receptacle are typically shorted on the PCB.
Why not in the receptacle itself then? Lines would need to cross diagonally over each other so maybe it was decided not to do that to reduce space and let the PCB designer handle that complexity.

Here is a reference https://www.digikey.com/en/articles/how-to-meet-new-usb4-gen-3-type-c-reliability-and-signal-integrity-requirements

Comment: On the plug they are not shorted, on the receptacle they must be.